# Excel date formatting convert to number

Tags: excel, date, time

I have a data file imported where there is a column for the date. It is custom formatted as `[-$409]ddmmmyyyy h:mm:ss:000` so that it takes a number like `41769.68` and has it shown in the cell as `10May2014 16:23:04.883`, for instance.

I want to be able to take just the hour and use that for conditional formatting though. For example, if the hour is between 7AM and 11AM, I want another column to say 'morning', or something of that sort. I know I can change the format cells option to just 'h' to get the hour, but using that in another block of code still returns the original `41749.68` number rather than `16`, for example.

Is there a way to get just the hour to show in its actual number form rather than the whole date, or if not, is there a way to parse the number `41769.68` to find the hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hour is .68 (the decimal part) *24 (each day is 1 unit to Excel). If you don't want the minutes then either round or truncate (eg with INT). Either way Conditional Formatting will not allow you to format as 'morning'.

You could try:

```
=HOUR(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your value in **A1,** in another cell enter:

```
=INT(24*(A1-INT(A1)))
```

will display **16**